# Banning IP addresses after repeated login attempts to specific URL

Tags: php, iptables, bash, centos7

I have a few questions regarding banning IP addresses after x many login attempts to a certain url on my website. Mostly, what would be the recommended or most efficient way?

**Example URL:**

```
https://example.com/login.php?=username&password
```

I'm familiar with `fail2ban`, although it's overkill. I only need to ban ip addresses trying to brute-force logins for the url mentioned above. Currently I log all attempts to a file, and coding a script that counts the ip addresses and automatically drops them from `IPTABLES` isn't really an issue.

The thing is, `IPTABLES` get quite lengthy and messy doing it this way, so maybe there's a better solution that keeps everything more organized? Also when hundreds of IP addresses are in the `IPTABLES` does it slow anything down?

Comment: Fail2ban is the best way to do this.

Comment: You should probably use mod_security for this. It is cleaner.

Comment: @AndreasRehm: But doesn't `fail2ban` look at concurrent connections?

Comment: fail2ban also blocks a lot of other bad activity to your server, and it only has to read the log files once. It's a good idea to have it running anyway.

Comment: @YoshiMiro fail2ban looks at the Logs. So every single logged and failed login counts.